# Cannot write to NTFS partitions after upgrade to Kernel 6.2 (Ubuntu 22.04LTS, xfce)

Tags: xfce, ntfs

I am dual-booting Windows 10 with Ubuntu (both OS reside on different physical disks).

I am using XFCE desktop, not a clean Xubuntu install, but changed from a standard Ubuntu installation a while ago.

**Before** the recent upgrade to kernel 6.2, I could access the NTFS partitions of the Windows 10 installation simply by clicking their icons on the desktop or in the Thunar file manager. Files could be read and written on the NTFS partitions with no issues.

**After** the update I can still read files from the NTFS partitions, but absolutely no write access is possible. I noticed this first when I tried to open a LibreOffice document and LibreOffice displayed an error message:

> Document Could Not Be Locked
> The lock file could not be created for exclusive access by LibreOffice due to missing permissions to create a  lock file on that file location or lack of free disk space.

The partition appears to be mounted r/w however (from my `/etc/mtab`)

```
/dev/sdd1 /media/{REDACTED}/System ntfs3 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,windows_names 0 0
```

I can mount from the terminal (as root), which defaults to using FUSE instead (again from `/etc/mtab`), and read/write access works fine.

```sh
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/{REDACTED}/mnt-tmp
```

```
/dev/sdb2 /media/{REDACTED}/mnt-tmp fuseblk rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

There are no special rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d` and `/etc/udisks2`

Comment: Are you sure your NTFS partition(s) are *clean*, as any mount that is *unclean* (*hibernated, fast-boot enabled etc*) will *flip* from RW to RO at mount to prevent data loss; with messages appearing in your system logs (or shown at terminal if you mounted at terminal).

Comment: This is all I see in `/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` output respectively:

> Aug 17 17:54:36 linux kernel: [41051.892132] ntfs3: Max link count 4000
> Aug 17 17:54:36 linux kernel: [41051.892134] ntfs3: Enabled Linux POSIX ACLs support
> Aug 17 17:54:36 linux kernel: [41051.892135] ntfs3: Read-only LZX/Xpress compression included
> Aug 17 17:54:03 linux rtkit-daemon[3046]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
> Aug 17 17:54:36 linux udisksd[1609]: Mounted /dev/sdd1 at /media/{REDACTED}/System on behalf of uid 1000

Both hibernation and windows fastboot are disabled.